# Fill area outside the rotated image using ImageSharp

Tags: c#, imagesharp

I am trying to draw two images on the other and when I rotate one of them, a black area appears around it
[image]

```
        using Image punchImage = await Image.LoadAsync(Path.Combine(imgPath, img));
        using Image authorPfpImage = PathClass.GetAvatarImageFromUrlPath(author).Result;
        using Image victimPfpImage = PathClass.GetAvatarImageFromUrlPath(user).Result;

        authorPfpImage.Mutate(img => img
            .Resize(new Size(authorPfpImage.Width + sizeAdjust[0, 0], authorPfpImage.Height + sizeAdjust[0, 1]))
            .Rotate(rotationDegrees[0]));
        victimPfpImage.Mutate(img => img
            .Resize(new Size(victimPfpImage.Width + sizeAdjust[1, 0], victimPfpImage.Height + sizeAdjust[1, 1]))
            .Rotate(rotationDegrees[1])
            );

        using Image outputImage = punchImage.Clone(img => img
            .DrawImage(victimPfpImage, new Point(points[0], points[1]), 1f)
            .DrawImage(authorPfpImage, new Point(points[2], points[3]), 1f)
        );

        string savePath = Path.Combine(imgPath, img.First() + img);
        await outputImage.SaveAsync(savePath);

        return savePath;
```

Is there some universal solution for this in ImageSharp? Couldn't find any information about this.

Comment: one of the images rotates fine for some reason smh

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps one of the images (i guess the authorPfpImage) already has a pixel format including alpha channel, thus allowing the regions of the rotated image that are not occupied by rotated pixels to be transparent. Whereas the other image might be in a pixel format without alpha channel, thus the image regions not occupied by rotated pixels will have some default non-transparant color value (like black in this instance). So, therefore, can you check the pixel formats used by both images?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, yea right, authorPfpImage is Rgba32 and victimPfpImage is Rgb24

Comment: Okay, then either you have to choose an image file for victimPfpImage that is rgba, or if that is not practical/feasible, you will need to convert the loaded image into one using rgba pixels. I don't know ImageSharp, though, so you will have to figure this out by yourself. (Check first if there are overloads for the image loading method(s) that allow specifiying a pixel format and are able to do the pixel format conversion on the fly while loading...)

Comment: Yea, i did it ty, now it works, i did it with CloneAs<Rgba32>() but i'm trying to find another way to convert it since i'm worried about memory leak of IDisposable object

Comment: I found more suitable for me, i just edited PathClass method GetCurrentDirectoryCombinedPath line LoadAsync to LoadAsync<Rgba32>

Answer (score 2):

This will be due to do the fact your source image doesn't get a transparency channel in the fast `Image.Load()` loading path, instead you want to make sure you load images using a specific pixel format that support transparency. i.e. instead of calling `Image.Load(fileSource)` call  `Image.Load<Rgba32>(fileSource)` instead.

Ideally you would update the `PathClass.GetAvatarImageFromUrlPath(author)` call to return an `Image<Rgba32>` but if this is an external/third party component that you can't update you can instead clone it into a new `Image<Rgba32>` this is however at the expense of memory.

```cs
using Image<Rgba32> punchImage = await Image.LoadAsync<Rgba32>(Path.Combine(imgPath, img));
using Image authorPfpImageSource = PathClass.GetAvatarImageFromUrlPath(author).Result;
using Image authorPfpImage = authorPfpImageSource.CloneAs<Rgba32>(); // force this image to have an alpha/transparency channel
using Image victimPfpImageSource = PathClass.GetAvatarImageFromUrlPath(user).Result;
using Image victimPfpImage = victimPfpImageSource.CloneAs<Rgba32>(); // force this image to have an alpha/transparency channel

authorPfpImage.Mutate(img => img
    .Resize(new Size(authorPfpImage.Width + sizeAdjust[0, 0], authorPfpImage.Height + sizeAdjust[0, 1]))
    .Rotate(rotationDegrees[0]));
victimPfpImage.Mutate(img => img
    .Resize(new Size(victimPfpImage.Width + sizeAdjust[1, 0], victimPfpImage.Height + sizeAdjust[1, 1]))
    .Rotate(rotationDegrees[1])
    );

punchImage.Mutate(img => img
    .DrawImage(victimPfpImage, new Point(points[0], points[1]), 1f)
    .DrawImage(authorPfpImage, new Point(points[2], points[3]), 1f)
);

string savePath = Path.Combine(imgPath, img.First() + img);
await punchImage.SaveAsync(savePath);

return savePath;
```